# Cloud Functions deployment fails with "Failed to retrieve function source code"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I deployed Cloud Functions from Cloud Source Repositries, I got a "Failed to retrieve function source code" and the deployment failed.

Some of the Cloud Functions currently running are deployed from Cloud Source Repositries, so I copied and deployed it, but I get the same error.

Deployment is done with GUI and Python 3.8 is used.

I didn't get this error until last week.

I've found information that there is a problem with the GCP payment method, but I haven't changed my payment information recently.

Please tell me what is the cause.
I'm sorry if I'm not good at English and it's hard to read.
Thank you.

```
{
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
status: {
code: 3
message: "Failed to retrieve function source code"
}
authenticationInfo: {
principalEmail: "xxxxxx@xxxxxx"
}
serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"
methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"
resourceName: "projects/xxxxxx/locations/asia-northeast1/functions/xxxxxx"
}
insertId: "-xxxxxx"
resource: {
type: "cloud_function"
labels: {
project_id: "xxxxxx"
function_name: "xxxxxx"
region: "asia-northeast1"
}
}
timestamp: "2021-02-03T10:56:30.332588Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logName: "projects/xxxxxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
operation: {
id: "xxxxxxx"
producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"
last: true
}
receiveTimestamp: "2021-02-03T10:56:30.618763199Z"
}
```

Comment: There may be hundreds of reasons. Can you check the Stackdriver log to see any details there, please?

Comment: How do you deploy your Cloud Functions?

Comment: @al-dann
Thank you for your reply. I pasted the log at the beginning of the thread.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere 
Thank you for your reply.I opened Cloud Functions in the GUI and created it from there. SourceCode is obtained from Cloud Source Repositories.

Comment: and you have only one log message, have not you? I mean, in my experience, there should be a few (3 or 4) lines in logs, so it should be possible to get a bit more details about the failure reasons.

Comment: @al-dann Only this one log was output after deployment.
There are a few lines for other errors, but this time it was the only one.

Comment: CHange branch from main to master https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70431064/head-of-cloud-source-repository-is-not-pointing-to-any-commit. It did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I deployed it now and it was successful.
The procedure is exactly the same as last time.

I think it's a GCP bug, but there was no failure information.
https://status.cloud.google.com/

I've solved it, so I'll close it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you changed any files in your CSR before the issue resolved, by any chance?

Comment: For some users, it might also help to re-enable the *Cloud Functions* and the *Cloud Source Repositories* APIs.

Comment: @DenisT. 
Thank you for your reply.
No, I haven't changed the CSR file.
If the same thing happens in the future, try re-enable.